# Pointfree functions in Haskell - turning arguments into a list

Tags: haskell

I am looking at some functions in Haskell in point-free style. While trying to rewrite some easy examples, I got stuck at this one

`func a b c d = sum $ take 2 $ sort [a, b, c, d]`

How to turn the arguments into a list form so that I don't need to write `a b c` on the left handside?

Comment: `((((((sum . take 2) .) . sort) .) .) .) . (. ((. ((. return) . (:))) . (.) . (:))) . (.) . (.) . (:)` but why would you ever want that?

Comment: `sum . take 2 . sort $ [a, b, c, d]` is easier on the eyes.

Comment: @n.m going through [the course materials from TUM](http://www21.in.tum.de/teaching/info2/WS1314/wettbewerb.html) and see that people need to minimize the tokens to win the in-lecture competition. So I am thinking about tricks to drop the arguments and found point-free style.

Comment: Note that `[a, b, c, d]` is just syntactic sugar for `(:) a ((:) b ((:) c ((:) d [])))`. Pointfree notation doesn't get the benefit of sugar, so you're already off to a really bad start.

Answer (score 2):

Someone in the comments mentioned awesome

```
((((((sum . take 2) .) . sort) .) .) .) . (. ((. ((. return) . (:))) . (.) . (:))) . (.) . (.) . (:)
```

function.

According to http://pointfree.io

```
((((sum . take 2 . sort) .) .) .) . (. ((. ((. return) . (:))) . (.) . (:))) . (.) . (.) . (:)
```

will be correct as well.

Don't you believe me?

**OKAY**

Let's beta-reduct the second option (it looks nicer imo)

```
(((((sum . take 2 . sort) .) .) .) . (. ((. ((. return) . (:))) . (.) . (:))) . (.) . (.) . (:) ) a b c d
```

Apply it to `a`:

```
((((((sum . take 2 . sort) .) .) .) ((. ((. ((. return) . (:))) . (.) . (:))) ((.) ((.) ((:) a))))) ) b c d
```

Ensugar operators:

```
((((((sum . take 2 . sort) .) .) .) ((. ((. ((. return) . (:))) . (.) . (:))) (((a:).).))) ) b c d
```

Apply partially applied composition:

```
((((sum . take 2 . sort) .) .) . ((. ((. ((. return) . (:))) . (.) . (:))) (((a:).).))) b c d
```

Apply it to `b`:

```
((((sum . take 2 . sort) .) .) (((. ((. ((. return) . (:))) . (.) . (:))) (((a:).).)) b)) c d
```

Compute function that will be applied to `b` by applying partially applied `.`:

```
((((sum . take 2 . sort) .) .) ( (((a:).).) . ((. ((. return) . (:))) . (.) . (:)) $ b)) c d)
```

Resolve composition:

```
((((sum . take 2 . sort) .) .) ( (((a:).).) (((. ((. return) . (:))) . (.) . (:)) b))) c d
```

Apply to `b`:

```
((((sum . take 2 . sort) .) .) ( (((a:).).) ((. ((. return) . (:))) ((b:) .)))) c d
```

Apply composition (2x):

```
(((sum . take 2 . sort) .) . ((((a:).).) (( ((b:) .) . ((. return) . (:)))))) c d
```

Apply to `c` and resolve composition:

```
((sum . take 2 . sort) .) (((((a:).).) (( ((b:) .) . ((. return) . (:))))) c) d
```

Apply partially applied composition:

```
((sum . take 2 . sort) .) (((((a:).) . (( ((b:) .) . ((. return) . (:)))))) c) d
```

Apply to `c` and resolve composition:

```
((sum . take 2 . sort) .) (((a:).) ((( ((b:) .) . ((. return) . (:)))) c)) d
```

Apply to `c` and resolve composition:

```
((sum . take 2 . sort) .) (((a:).) (((b:) .) (((. return) . (:)) c))) d
```

Resolve composition:

```
((sum . take 2 . sort) .) ((a:) . (((b:) .) (((. return) . (:)) c))) d
```

Apply partially applied composition:

```
((sum . take 2 . sort) . ((a:) . (((b:) .) (((. return) . (:)) c)))) d
```

Resolve composition:

```
(sum . take 2 . sort) (((a:) . (((b:) .) (((. return) . (:)) c))) d)
```

Apply to `d` and resolve composition:

```
(sum . take 2 . sort) ((a:) ((((b:) .) (((. return) . (:)) c)) d))
```

Apply partially applied composition:

```
(sum . take 2 . sort) ((a:) (((b:) . (((. return) . (:)) c)) d))
```

Apply to `d` and resolve composition:

```
(sum . take 2 . sort) ((a:) (((b:) ((((. return) . (:)) c) d))))
```

Apply to `c` and resolve composition:

```
(sum . take 2 . sort) ((a:) (((b:) (((((c:). return))) d))))
```

Apply to `d` and resolve composition:

```
(sum . take 2 . sort) ((a:) ((b:) ((c:) (return d))))
```

Transform to infix operators and resolve `return`

```
(sum . take 2 . sort) (a : (b : (c : (d : []))))
```

Ensugar

```
(sum . take 2 . sort) [a, b, c, d]
```

Resolve compositions and use `$` operator

```
sum $ take 2 $ sort $ [a, b, c, d]
```

And hell we are!
It will be easier to read if you paste it to editor with rainbow brackets.

---

As you see not everything will look more elegant in pointfree form. Sometimes it is very non trivial and it may be very confusing to understand not only *why* does the function work, but *what* does it even do. Note that this function is length-specific – it will grow much larger if you try to create bigger lists this way.

On the other hand I often use http://pointfree.io to check if my chain of functions can be expressed in a simpler way. They key is to find the golden mean – in some cases this form can help, but sometimes it turns to be not only "point-free", but also "point-less" notation.

Answer (score 2):

If I wanted to write this pointfree in real code, I’d just factor out the construction of the list:

```
list4 a b c d = [a, b, c, d]
under3 = fmap . fmap . fmap
func = under3 (sum . take 2 . sort) . list4

func 30 4 1000 200 == 34
```

`under3` “skips” 3 arguments using `fmap` in the `(->) a` functor so we can compose a 1-argument function (`sum . take2 . sort`) with a 4-argument one (`list4`)—this use of `fmap` is exactly equivalent to composition `(.)`, just a bit more readable than inlining it, since mnemonically it’s “mapping over” arguments:

```
func = ((((sum . take 2 . sort) .) .) .) . list4
  where
    …
```

`list4` itself doesn’t really need to be pointfree, since there’s no straightforward way to make it more readable & succinct than the pointful version. You can write it pointfree a little more readably if you’re willing to build the list in reverse and `reverse` it afterward, but it’s still a bit long and not very clear:

```
list4 = under3 reverse . fmap (fmap cons . cons) . cons . pure
  where cons = flip (:)
```